# take the grandson of a div element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this html code:

```
 <div class="toCommit-slide active3 first">
        <p>
          <img src"something">
        </p>
 </div>
 <div class="toCommit-slide active3 first">
        <p>
          <img src"something">
        </p>
 </div>
 <div class="toCommit-slide active3 first">
        <p>
          <img src"something">
        </p>
 </div>
```

I want to take the img inside the p tag, with jquery for example I could use something like .closest (), but in javascript? I need a pure javascript code.
I can't give class to p tags and img tags, because they are automatically generated by a CMS.

Comment: Which of those img tags is "_the img_"?

Comment: Tried `document.querySelector('div img')` yet? Youll need to add correct ids on the divs or something to get the one you want. Or use `div:nth-child(x)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
const img = document.querySelector('.toCommit-slide.active3.first img');
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.toCommit-slide.active3.first img');

console.log(img);
console.log([...imgs]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="toCommit-slide active3 first">
        <p>
            <img src"something">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="toCommit-slide active3 first">
        <p>
            <img src"something">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="toCommit-slide active3 first">
        <p>
            <img src"something">
        </p>
    </div>

    
</body>

</html>
```